# Perform segue on viewcontroller's startup

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a login screen and what I want to do is to detect whether the user is already logged in and eventually popup a modal.

I created a custom segue that shown the modal with no animation.

```
@implementation NonAnimatedSegue

-(void) perform {

    [self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];

}
```

The thing is that calling this segue from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear takes no effect. If I call it from viewDidAppear, the login screen flicks for a while before the modal opens.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: it should work from viewWillAppear

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava This doesn't work, you get a warning saying "Attempt to present viewB on viewA whose view is not in the window heirarchy!"

Comment: You should consider having two storyboards, one for Login related flow and another one for normal flow.Should check the login status in appDelegate and instantiate storyboard accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this problem was to check in the application finished launching and set the root view controller as needed. Like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /*stuff*/
    /*get the view controller from storyboard/nib*/
    [self.window setRootViewController:CorrectViewController];
}
```

It wouldn't show a modal view but just show the login on launch.